# Layout pages doesn't inherit master page in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a site in a site collection. 
I have modified the master page of my sub-site to have a fixed width of 960px. This is working fine for all the pages, lists, libraries except for in-built layout pages, for example, on click of 'All Site Content', the page is occupying the full size width instead of 960px.

How can i fix this issue..

Answer (score 0):

The content displayed in View ALl site content is using Table , TH,Tr, TD structure to display data and it has width set as 100% by defualt.

So if you want to provide the fixed width of 960px then you have to change that setting using Sharepoint designer.

Correct me If I am wrong in this.

One More thing if you have your own custom master page then you have to apply it to the application pages also.

Goto Siteaction > Site Settings > Under Site Master Page Settings click Master Pages

If you have your custom master page then apply it in "System Master Page" section

Thanks

Comment: I have applied my custom master page to "System Master Page" as-well-as "Site master page", but no luck..